# How to properly Organize Firebase Functions in Groups?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am following [This Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#group_functions) to create a Functions project with multiple function files in NodeJS. while this is a good base, it does not show how to properly initiate a firebase app by using **const app = admin.initializeApp()** in a way that could be reused across the different files. my initial thought was to add the following in index.ts and import app as needed, but this raises a **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error.

```
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
export const app = admin.initializeApp();
```

While searching online I could only find some older posts that don't apply to current versions. can anyone provide a guideline for this?

Comment: Can you check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add-sdk) once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) issue. You need to initialize Firebase Admin only once at the beginning of `index.ts` and import other services as needed in other files as shown below:

```
// index.ts
// Don't export anything from this file. 

import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";

initializeApp({
  databaseURL: "<DB_URL>",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
});

export * from "./metric";
```

```
// metric.ts

import { https } from "firebase-functions/v1";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";

const db = getFirestore();

export const test = https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const metricData = await db.collection("metrics").get();
  res.json(metricData.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
});
```